# Mailchimp alternatives for non-marketing email

Tags: mailing-list, newsletter

I'm setting up a paid subscription daily email newsletter that will likely stay under 1000 recipients for the foreseeable future. It must include large PDF attachments (1-5mb) and I want them to be attachments, not links, which seems to rule out Mailchimp.

Basically I'd like the responsive formatting, tracking and list management of Mailchimp (which I obviously don't get just BCCing everyone in a regular email) but without as much of the high-volume or marketing features.

Does something like this exist?